# XPath and attributes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I'm trying to traverse an XML document and select certain node attributes. The XML is dynamically generated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<streams>
<stream>
<title>+23 (Panama)</title>
<info resolution="768x420" bitrate="1000kbps"/> ----- Need These
<swfUrl>http://www.freeetv.com/script/mediaplayer/player.swf</swfUrl>
<link>rtmp://200.75.216.156/live/</link>
<pageUrl>http://www.freeetv.com/</pageUrl>
<playpath>livestream</playpath>
<language>Music</language>
<advanced></advanced>
</stream>
</streams>
```

The code that I'm trying to use with zero luck and Visual Studio saying "No you're wrong. Try 600 more times" is

```
xDoc.Load("http://127.0.0.1/www/xml.php");

                XmlNodeList nodes = xDoc.SelectNodes("/streams/stream");
                foreach (XmlNode xn in nodes)
                {
                    ListViewItem lvi = listView1.Items.Add(xn["title"].InnerText);
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(xn["swfUrl"].InnerText);
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(xn["link"].InnerText);
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(xn["pageUrl"].InnerText);
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(xn["playpath"].InnerText);
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(xn["language"].InnerText);
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(xn["advanced"].InnerText);
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(xn["//info/@resolution"].Value);
                }
```

Please tell me oh wise ones what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The devil is in the detail. The docs (and Intellisense) for the default indexer of `XmlNode` say _"The first **XmlElement** that matches the specified name."_. Attributes aren't elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to select node's attribute using XPath you should use `SelectSingleNode` method, e.g.:

```
xn.SelectSingleNode("info/@resolution").Value
```

Answer (score 2):

To select `resolution` attribute of your last node you need to use:

```
xn["info"].Attributes["resolution"].Value
```

Alternatively, you can try LINQ to XML for the same results (I find its API easier to use):

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse("http://127.0.0.1/www/xml.php");

foreach (var d in doc.Descendants("stream"))
{
    ListViewItem lvi = listView1.Items.Add(d.Element("title").Value);
    lvi.SubItems.Add(d.Element("swfUrl").Value);
    // ...
    vi.SubItems.Add(d.Element("info").Attribute("resolution").Value);
}
```

Comment: Good practice is to check if attribute != null before get Value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of LINQ to XML to extract attributes from the entire document of a particular attribute name OR list of attribute names.

```
var xml = XElement.Parse("http://127.0.0.1/www/xml.php");

// find all attributes of a given name
var attributes = xml
     .Descendants()
     .Attributes("AttributeName")

// find all attributes of multiple names
var attributes = xml
    .Descendants()
    .Attributes()
    .Where(a => ListOfAttribNames.Contains(a.Name.LocalName))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Replace**:

```
lvi.SubItems.Add(xn["//info/@resolution"].Value);
```

**with**:

```
lvi.SubItems.Add(xn.SelectSingleNode("info/@resolution").Value);
```

Comment: It isn't but you may not believe this statement...I see your answer just *now*, and probably the reason is that it is just a hint, whereas I tell the OP what he needs to do so that after performing the modification his code will work as intended. Please, copy and paste *my* answer into yours and I'll delete my answer.